# How to reduce execution time in long video using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg for adding text over video and add overlay image over video in android everything works for me but it takes too long to execute command mostly in long video that more than or equals to 10 sec

```
 String  imgcmd[]=new String[]{"-i", inputpath ,"-i",imagepath ,"-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10", "-codec:a", "copy",output};

                    String[] txtcmd = new String[]{"-i",""+inputpath, "-filter_complex", "drawtext=text=Vikram Dulagach:fontcolor=#000000:fontsize=54:x=533:y=503:fontfile="+"/sdcard/retro.ttf", "-y" ,""+output};
```

I want reduce execution time in ffmpeg

Comment: Is the output from the first ffmpeg command being used as the input for the second ffmpeg command?

Comment: no both are separate command and use different occasion

Comment: Not enough info to provide any suggestions. 1. Show an example of the actual ffmpeg commands being executed: not just the code that executes the commands. 2. Show the complete log from each command.

Comment: below code i am using to add image as overlay  and text at the bottom in video..but it will take more than 2 min or 3 min in 20 sec or 15 sec video..

Comment: sorry about that actually i do not know how to use  stack overflow..